# Efficiency/design of trim() library code

Tags: c++, performance, strings, c++11, library

I am working on some library code and I am trying to optimize my `trim()` functions. To that effect I am trying to figure out how best to deal with each kind of input. Move semantics are starting to fry my brains a little. Sometimes I think I understand them... but not very often.

What I want to do with this piece of code is take advice in all areas:

**Nomenclature:**

I am open to suggestions for function names. For example do I name them after the type of parameter or the type of value (`trim_cref` vs `trim_rval`)? What do people prefer?

**Unified function name based on overloads:**

Also it would be nice to end up with a universal set of functions that select the most efficient method based on input parameter without having a suffix to select between them:

```
std::string trim(std::string s);
std::string& trim(std::string& s); // mutating
std::string trim(std::string&& s);
std::string trim(const std::string& s);
```

I am pretty sure that's not completely achievable due to ambiguity. The question is what version should I leave out? The copy or the mutating?

**Efficiency of basic algorithm:**

I am using this basic algorithm:

```
std::string& trim(std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(t));
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(t) + 1);
    return s;
}
```

I would like to think the library is smart enough to special-case `s.erase()` when the first parameter is zero or the last parameter is `std::string::npos`. If not is there a faster way to do this?

**Efficiency of calling:**

I have implemented these functions in terms of each other, but I am not sure (at all) if what I have done is most efficient. Or even if I am not reducing efficiency (by inhibiting RVO for example).

**Am I even on the right track?**

Do I even need 4 functions (or overloads)? Would it be just as efficient to simply take parameters as copies and rely on RVO?

```
const char* const ws = " \t\n\r\f\v";

inline std::string& ltrim_mute(std::string& s, const char* t);
inline std::string ltrim_move(std::string&& s, const char* t);
inline std::string ltrim_cref(const std::string& s, const char* t);
inline std::string ltrim_copy(std::string s, const char* t);

inline std::string& rtrim_mute(std::string& s, const char* t);
inline std::string rtrim_move(std::string&& s, const char* t);
inline std::string rtrim_cref(const std::string& s, const char* t);
inline std::string rtrim_copy(std::string s, const char* t);

inline std::string& trim_mute(std::string& s, const char* t);
inline std::string trim_move(std::string&& s, const char* t);
inline std::string trim_cref(const std::string& s, const char* t);
inline std::string trim_copy(std::string s, const char* t);

// LEFT

inline std::string& ltrim_mute(std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(t));
    return s;
}

inline std::string ltrim_move(std::string&& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(ltrim_mute(s, t));
}

inline std::string ltrim_cref(const std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(ltrim_move(std::string(s),t));
}

inline std::string ltrim_copy(std::string s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(ltrim_move(std::move(s),t));
}

// RIGHT

inline std::string& rtrim_mute(std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(t) + 1);
    return s;
}

inline std::string rtrim_move(std::string&& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(rtrim_mute(s, t));
}

inline std::string rtrim_cref(const std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(rtrim_copy(s, t));
}

inline std::string rtrim_copy(std::string s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(rtrim_move(std::move(s),t));
}

// BOTH

inline std::string& trim_mute(std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return rtrim_mute(ltrim_mute(s, t), t);
}

inline std::string trim_move(std::string&& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(rtrim_mute(ltrim_mute(s, t), t));
}

inline std::string trim_cref(const std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(rtrim_move(ltrim_cref(s, t), t));
}

inline std::string trim_copy(std::string s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return std::move(rtrim_mute(ltrim_mute(s, t), t));
}
```

Comment: Do not [return by `std::move()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11817902/3033711).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll take a swing at this:

> 2) Unified function name based on overloads:
>   ...
>   Also it would be nice to end up with a universal set of functions that select the most efficient method based on input parameter without having a suffix to select between them:
>   ...
>   I am pretty sure that's not completely achievable due to ambiguity. The question is what version should I leave out? The copy or the mutating?

I think that it would be a very bad idea to have 2 overloads of the same function name where one mutates its argument and the other returns a copy.  Overloads that don't perform the same semantic operation shouldn't be overloads, at least in my mind.  So, I'd pick 2 different names instead, say "inplace_trim" and "trim".  If you take that approach, then it would make perfect sense to have overloaded versions of "trim" for by-value, by-reference, by-const-reference, and by-xvalue.

This also solves:

> 1) Nomenclature:
>
> I am open to suggestions for function names. For example do I name them after the type of parameter or the type of value (trim_cref vs trim_rval)?

This way you only need to have 2 names, "inplace_trim" and "trim".  You don't need any funky naming convention since it allows overloading to work.

> 3) Efficiency of basic algorithm:

I have only one thought here, and it's a minor one: It will be slightly more efficient to trim the trailing whitespace first, then the leading.  The reason is that `erase`ing from the front of a string is just like `erase`ing from the front of a vector; it requires copying every character after the erasure point into its new location in the sequence.  Erasing from the end just updates pointers, so if you do the erase from the end first, there are fewer characters needing copying during the erase from the beginning.

> Efficiency of calling:

It has just occurred to me that you're doing more copying than necessary in the case where there are actually leading spaces in your strings.  The way that you implement `ltrim_cref`, for instance, you copy the input string and pass the copy into `ltrim_move`, which then deletes the leading whitespace by shifting every character after the erasure point left (another hidden copy).  You could avoid this extra copy by instead doing (untested):

```
inline std::string ltrim_cref(const std::string& s, const char* t = ws)
{
    return s.substr(std::min(s.size(), s.find_first_not_of(t)));
}
```

So it seems like, by trying to implement these functions in terms of each other, you may be missing out on some optimization opportunities.

Other thoughts:

1. I'd rename `t` to `chars_to_skip` or something like that - `t` isn't a particularly meaningful name.
2. If `ws` is going to be exposed as part of your API through your header file, I'd make sure that a) it's in a namespace to avoid namespace pollution, and b) it gets a more descriptive name, like `StringTrimming::ASCII_WHITESPACE`.

Comment: Great points. Funny thing is I was originally using only two function names (one for copy, one for mutate) before I decided to try to get clever about it in order to try to take advantage of rvalue references. You are completely right about not mixing semantics.

Comment: @Galik, I just added some points about "Efficiency of calling" that I just thought of.  Also, on a similar line of thinking, depending on how much you care about efficiency you may want to consider using Boost's string_ref here - that would let you return something string-like, without ever needing to pay the cost for a copy under any circumstance (you'd have to pay the managerial overhead of ensuring the original string being referenced stays valid, instead).

Comment: +1 "I'd rename t to chars_to_skip or something like that - t isn't a particularly meaningful name." "If ws is going to be exposed as part of your API through your header file, I'd make sure that a) it's in a namespace to avoid namespace pollution, and b) it gets a more descriptive name, like StringTrimming::ASCII_WHITESPACE." Meaningful names are everything.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to concentrate primarily on one (admittedly rather minor) aspect of the code--specifically, where you pass a C-style string to specify what should be treated as white space.

Although some would argue that they're terribly (over?) engineered, the standard library already has `locale`s and `ctype` facets specifically intended for this task. These have the disadvantage of being clumsy to use, but this is often outweighed by two advantages: their interface is defined as part of the standard, and (associated with that) the correct values to use for a particular locale are normally encoded into a pre-defined objects.

In particular, you can create a locale object using an empty name ("") that corresponds to the settings in the user's environment (e.g., is based on the language they've specified for their operating system installation). Using this, you can write code to "do the right thing" without client code even needing to be aware of what "the right thing" really is (i.e., without knowledge of what characters are considered white space in the end-user's installation).

As noted above, the code to use this is somewhat ugly though. `locale` contains a `use_facet`, which (in turn) can use the facet's `scan_is` and/or `scan_not` functions to scan for a value that fits/doesn't fit a particular classification. Unfortunately, these are based on raw character buffers and raw pointers instead of using iterators. As a result, they can scan for the first character that's not white space (as specified by that ctype facet) but *not* at all easily for the last.

As such, if you're going to use/support facets, you probably want to do your own scanning functions, and just use the ctype facet's `is` member function.

For a simple example, code might look something like this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

namespace {
    template <class It>
    It trim(It b, It e) {
        typedef std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type charT;

        std::locale loc("");

        for (; b != e; ++b)
            if (!std::use_facet<std::ctype<charT> >(loc).is(std::ctype_base::space, *b))
                break;
        return b;
    }
}

std::string trim_left(std::string const &input) {
    return std::string(trim(input.begin(), input.end()), input.end());
}

std::string trim_right(std::string const &input) {
    return std::string(input.begin(), trim(input.rbegin(), input.rend()).base());
}

std::string trim_both(std::string const &input) {
    return std::string(trim(input.begin(), input.end()), trim(input.rbegin(), input.rend()).base());
}

int main(){ 
    std::string input = "\t   this    \v";

    std::cout << "Trim left\t\"" << trim_left(input) << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Trim right\t\"" << trim_right(input) << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Trim both\t\"" << trim_both(input) << "\"\n";
}
```

For simplicity, I've implemented only one variant of the functions (create a new string), but since `trim` just deals in iterators, it's fairly easy to create the other front-ends to modify the string in-place rather than creating a new string.

Likewise, I've just created a nameless locale on the fly. For real use you probably want to pass that as a parameter (with a default value) instead. That way, if the user has their computer configured for, say, French as used in Belgium but wants to process text as Portuguese as used in Brazil, they can do that pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you @Jerry this is valued input. I think the main reasons I shied away from using the locale are that 1) speed, sometings it may be only tabs or spaces that need stripping, not all "whitespace"  (2) Sometimes it is not spaces at all that I want to trim, it could be brackets, parens, punctuation etc... That is why I left it for the user to supply the characters. In my test. my method is many times faster than boost::trim. But I will definitely look into your suggestions here, like using iterators and traits. Perhaps I can find a neat way to accommodate both approaches.

Comment: @Galik: Although it may seem (and may well *be*) rather roundabout, it's entirely possible to define a ctype facet that classifies the characters of your choice as white space, then supply that to the routine. I've often done this when using the facet with a stream. e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/10376445/179910

Comment: @Galik: As far as speed goes, I'd have to profile to be sure, but I'd guess there's a bit of a tradeoff. Creating the locale is probably fairly slow. Using it is probably pretty fast. It's normally table-driven, so it's constant complexity, regardless of number of characters you classify as white space (whereas `find_first_not_of` will normally be linear).